# Differentiation of power law

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value, mathematica

Hi all I am trying to differentiate with respect to the torsion tensor $T$ the power-law model by Bengochea and Ferraro which is given by

$f(T) = \beta|T|^{n}$

Mathematica has given me the result:

$f'(T) = n \beta |T|^{n-1} |T'|$

Therefore should $|T'|$ be equal to $1$? I believe that I am incorrect in my reasoning. I would appreciate any assistance on the matter.

Comment: Which norm are you using on $T$?

Comment: T is a function of time t so I should have written $T(t)$ and I am differentiating with respect to time $t$

Comment: But which NORM are you using on $T$?